# Draw the Polyline with border

Tags: c#, wpf, polyline

I'm using WPF to draw the polyline with certain width, the sample code is as follows:

> DrawingContext.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Yellow, new Pen(Brush,
>   polylineWidth), streamGeometry);

where the streamGeometry is the geometry of the polyline.
The result Looks like:
[image]

However, I'd like to add borders around the polyline, which looks like:

[image]
[image]

I know I can draw two polylines with different width (one for the black background, and the other for the color I want to render)
I just wonder is there any API or some  elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: There might be some merit to looking at using pixel shaders in WPF. I haven't got much experience of it myself, so I'm not sure which resource to recommend.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one additional step needed to accomplish that. Create a new shape out of your polyline (the thickness of the polyline included). Use:

```
var pathGeometry = streamGeometry.GetWidenedPathGeometry (new Pen(Brushes.Black, polylineWidth));
```

Then call

```
DrawingContext.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Yellow, new Pen(strokeBrush, strokeThickness), pathGeometry);
```

and you are done.